# How to properly add inline Javascript?

Tags: 8, javascript

Now that `drupal_add_js(...., 'inline')` is no longer possible, how can I inject dynamic Javascript from a custom module's Controller? (I'm trying to upgrade a D6 module with as little refactorings as possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approach it a number of ways. You can add it to the #attached property in hook_preprocess_page or hook_preprocess_X. You can add it as a library in the #attached property of the array being returned for that request by the controller.

You will need to define some library definitions, as well.

See: https://www.drupal.org/node/2169605 and https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets

Comment: I like that this suggests to use #attached instead of inline JavaScript as that is much preferred. It is still possible to inject it inline with `_drupal_add_html_head`. For a deep discussion/debate about the specific use case where the order of JavaScript matters, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2391025.

Comment: I have also seen {{ attach ... }} called from a twig template.https://www.drupal.org/node/2456753

Comment: @mradcliffe I can't find any details (or code in core) about `_drupal_add_html_head` apart from a single reference in that discussion.

Answer (score 5):

I found a slightly easier way that might help folks.  I used this on a Drupal 9 site recently.

```
/**
* Implements hook_page_attachments().
*/
function mymodule_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {

  $useful = "Javascript could really use this";
  $js =  'console.log("i am here");window.usefulInfo = '. '"' . $useful . '"';
  $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
    [
      '#tag' => 'script',
      '#attributes' => [
        'type' => 'text/javascript',
      ],
      '#value' => $js,
    ],
    'key_for_this_snippet',
  ];
}
```

Comment: FYI: Unfortunately this only works in modules, but not in themes.

Answer (score 4):

If you want *inline* javascript in order to pass some computed variables, then it seems that the only way to do it in D8 is to use a combination of `drupalSettings` and an attached library.  The following snippets are copied from [Attaching configurable JavaScript](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module#configurable) in the official docs.

In `mymodule.libraries.yml`, declare a library containing your javascript file, with a dependency on `drupalSettings` (and on `jQuery`):

```
cuddly-slider:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/cuddly-slider.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
```

Then, when building (or altering) your render array, attach the library and save something to the settings:

```
$build['#attached']['library'][] = 'fluffiness/cuddly-slider';
$build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['fluffiness']['cuddlySlider']['foo'] = 'bar';
```

Presumably, you have something more interesting than `'bar'`.  Finally, access the setting in your javascript file as `drupalSettings.fluffiness.cuddlySlider.foo`.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases you would really want to add a snippet somewhere inside your code, inside *script* tags. This is how you do it:
Let's say you want the snippet inside a controller. Create a custom module and add a file named **google_snippet.routing.yml** with this content:

```
google_snippet.page:
  path: '/my-custom-path'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Here is my snippet'
    _controller: '\Drupal\google_snippet\Controller\snippetPage::render'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Also add a file **google_snippet.module** file to make the controller aware of a template file:

```
function google_snippet_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'google_snippet' => [
      'variables' => [
        'snippet' => NULL
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Create a file in **src/Controller/** named **snippetPage.php**.

```
namespace Drupal\google_snippet\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class snippetPage extends ControllerBase {
  public static function render() {
    return [
      '#theme' => 'google_snippet',
      '#snippet' => '
         <script>
          INSERT YOUR SNIPPET HERE
        </script>
      ',
    ];
  }
}
```

Then, inside a templates folder of your module a file named **google-snippet.html.twig** with the following content:

```
{{ snippet|raw }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ended up with something in the middle. Problem is: Without the template my JS code will end up escaped with HMTL entities.

```php
/** 
 * @file css_color_variables_ie11/css_color_variables_ie11.module
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function css_color_variables_ie11_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'css_color_variables_ie11' => [
      'variables' => [
        'script_source' => NULL
      ],
    ],
  ];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments_alter().
 */
function css_color_variables_ie11_page_attachments_alter(array &$page) {

  // [...] 

  $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
    [
      '#theme' => 'css_color_variables_ie11',
      '#script_source' => $sourcePath,
      '#tag' => 'script',
    ],
    'css_color_variables_ie11',
  ];
}
```

```
/*! ie11CustomProperties.js v4.1.0 | MIT License | https://git.io/fjXMN */
window.MSInputMethodContext && document.documentMode && document.write('<script src="{{ script_source }}"><\x2fscript>');
```

*css_color_variables_ie11/templates/css-color-variables-ie11.html.twig*

**Result (HTML source)**

```
<script>/*! ie11CustomProperties.js v4.1.0 | MIT License | https://git.io/fjXMN */
window.MSInputMethodContext && document.documentMode && document.write('<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nuxodin/ie11CustomProperties@4.1.0/ie11CustomProperties.min.js"><\x2fscript>');
</script>
```