# How to attach JSON data to JS variable without it being escaped

Tags: javascript, 8

I'm having so much trouble with drupal 8 right now.

when in Drupal 7 I could do:

```
drupal_add_js("var a = 'b';");
```

and be done with it, for the life of my, I can't figure out how to attach data to a JS variable in Drupal 8

I had to write a custom THEME_preprocess_page function to add the JSON value to drupalSettings like this:

```
$variables['page']['content']['#attached']['drupalSettings']['customPricelist'] = $result;
```

but in reality the result get's escaped with quotation marks like:

```
"{"some":"stuff"}"
```

and is not usable..

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly add inline Javascript?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197007/how-to-properly-add-inline-javascript)

Comment: I've seen that post and read all those articles, there's no information about how to manage what I'm trying.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that printing JavaScript code like that is bad practice. You should write a JavaScript script that uses variables from the drupalSettings object.

Comment: @Eyal: That's exactly what I'm trying to do, and this was me trying to put some data into the drupalSettings variable, which was being escaped with quotation marks and rendered unusable :)

Comment: When you access the drupalSettings object in JavaScript it is un-escaped.

Comment: @Eyal: The solution provided by rémy worked just adding the variable of JSON string didn't, and obviouslt I tested getting the variable value from drupalSettings with JavaScript, drupalSettings['customPricelist'] returned "{"some":"data"}" instead of an object {"some":"data"} hence was unusable

Comment: See my answer below on how to use the drupalSettings object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like:

```
$variables['page']['content']['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
    // The data.
    [
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      // The HTML tag to add, in this case a  tag.
      '#tag' => 'script',
      // The value of the HTML tag, here we want to end up with alert("Hello world!");.
       '#value' => 'alert("Hello world!");',
       // set attributes like src to load a file
       '#attributes' => array('src' => ''),

    ],
    // A key, to make it possible to recognize this HTML  element when altering.
    'hello-world'
  ];
}
```

Comment: It worked, Thank you! I've been going insane here pulling my hair out for hours.. How to come upon this sort of documentation or materials?

Comment: search for what you need. here inline javascript. in the answer I marked as duplicate, there the link to the change record, linking to where I copied this source from: https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets

Answer (score 1):

The best practice of passing data to the JavaScript client is via the drupalSettings object.

```
$page['#attached']['drupalSettings']['somekey'] = [
  'anotherkey' => 'somevalue' 
]
```

In JavaScript it is accessible like this:

```
var someValue = drupalSettings.somekey.anotherkey;
```

Comment: Just tried it, unfortunately still doesn't work, Rémy's solution is only thing so far. With your way I could store a string or integer but not an object and I assume neither an array as the "quotation marks" are still formed around the variable value. what I end up with is this: https://snag.gy/nksZfi.jpg however with Rémy's solution I get what I need which is an object: https://snag.gy/9vNETG.jpg

Comment: That is because you passed a php object to drupalSettings. You have two options: convert it to an associative array in the server side before passing it to drupalSettings or unserialize it on the JavaScript side with JSON decode.

Comment: the object I'm passing is already json_encoded by drupal_json_output in a custom page modules 'delivery callback' and for some reason works if implemented with '#value' => 'var custom = '.$return.';'; in rémy's code. I do appreciate you trying to help figure out how to do it by the best practice guidelines, however for some reason my D8 install doesn't wan't me to..

Comment: You should have mentioned that you are encoding it in the first place. When you encode it, it is being escaped. If you encode it then you must decode it.  If you put your undecoded associative array inside the drupalSettings then it will be available to you in JavaScript, just like in the example above.

Comment: e.g.:     $variables['#attached']['drupalSettings']['script_data'] = json_encode($jsonData);